# Need explanation and example of VB.NET code

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Can some help me give some sample code how to call this method?

```
Public Shared Function ReadObjects(Of T)(ByVal query As String, ByVal func As Func(Of IDataReader, T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim outbound As New List(Of T)

    Using connection As OleDbConnection = NewConnection()
        connection.Open()
        Using command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandTimeout = 0
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read()
                outbound.Add(func.Invoke(reader))
            End While
        End Using
        connection.Close()
    End Using

    Return outbound
End Function
```

Had no idea how to go about this one :)

Comment: Asking for code to implement code makes no sense at all. That code is already code. It already implements what it implements. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, I would write the function like this:

```
Public Shared Iterator Function ReadObjects(Of T)(query As String, transform As Func(Of IDataRecord, T), parameters As Action(Of OleDbParameterCollection)) As IEnumerable(Of T)

    Using connection As OleDbConnection = NewConnection()
    Using command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
        If parameters IsNot Nothing Then parameters(command.Parameters)
        command.CommandTimeout = 0

        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Yield transform(reader)
        End While
    End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

There are several changes here, but the most important is the ability to accept query parameters separate from the command string. Otherwise, the prior code would have forced you put **HUGE GAPING WIDE SECURITY VULNERABILITIES** into your application.

---

That out of the way, it sounds like you're asking how to call the method, and it's likely the `Func(Of IDataRecord, T)` argument is the confusing part... and now also the `Action(Of OleDbParameterCollection)`.

*Here's how to do it.*

First, let's get an example. Say you have an `Employee` table with columns for `ID`, `LastName`, and `FirstName`. You also have a class named `Employee`, with properties that match the column names. You have a variable named `lastName`, and you want to run a query to give you every record from the table where the value of the `LastName` column matches the value of the `lastName` variable. Then we loop through the results and write each Employee to the Console:

That would look like this:

```
Dim lastName As String = "Bilazon"
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE LastName = ?"
Dim employees = ReadObjects(SQL, 
    Function(e) New Employee() With {ID = e("ID"), LastName = e("LastName"), FirstName = e("FirstName")},
    Sub(p) p.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 25).Value = lastName)

For Each emp As Employee In employees
    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {emp.ID}{vbTab}Last Name: {emp.LastName}{vbTab}First Name: {emp.FirstName}")
Next
```

The inline `Function` and `Sub` expressions above are called [Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions).

I might futher make this code a little easier to write and understand by adding a Shared method called `FromDataRecord()` to my `Employee` class:

```
Public Shared Function FromDataRecord(row As IDataRecord) As Employee
    Return New Employee() With {
        ID = row("ID"),
        LastName = row("LastName"),
        FirstName = row("FirstName")
    }
End Function
```

This is especially valuable as the class adds more properties or gets more complex. Now the function call can also be simplified a bit:

```
Dim lastName As String = "Bilazon"
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE LastName = ?"
Dim employees = ReadObjects(SQL, Employee.FromDataRecord,
    Sub(p) p.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 25).Value = lastName)

For Each emp As Employee In employees
    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {emp.ID}{vbTab}Last Name: {emp.LastName}{vbTab}First Name: {emp.FirstName}")
Next
```

The next level up is moving the `ReadObjects()` method to it's own Module (and marking it private), so you also write a public method in the new Module for each of the queries you want to run.

Comment: Thanks so much Joel! Some clarification if I understand it correctly, so e is the instance of Employee and p is the instance of OleDbDataReader?

Comment: `e` is the datareader's current row. `p` is the OleDbCommand's `.Parameters` collection, so you can add query parameters in a _safe_ way, rather than using string concatenation to build the query (which is very much **NOT safe**).

Comment: @BernBilazon But it's my fault you had that kind of backwards... I just noticed I had put the new argument into the method definition in the wrong place (it's fixed now in the answer).

Comment: Wow, this is really in-depth!! Thanks so much for the explanation. This makes my day!

Comment: The next level up is moving the `ReadObjects()` method to it's own Module (and marking it private), so that you also write a public method in the new Module for each of the queries you want to run.